# PowerQuery: How to replace text with each column name for multiple columns

Tags: list, replace, foreach, powerquery

I'm trying to replace "x" in each column (excepts for the first 2 columns) with the column name in a table with an unknown number of columns but with at least 2 columns.

I found the code to change one column, but I want it to be dynamic:

```
#"Ersatt värde" = Table.ReplaceValue(Källa,"x", Table.ColumnNames(Källa){2},Replacer.ReplaceText,{Table.ColumnNames(Källa){2}})
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you can try either approach below:

```
#"Ersatt värde" = 
    let
        columnsToTransform = List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Källa), 2),
        accumulated = List.Accumulate(columnsToTransform, Källa, (tableState as table, columnName as text) =>
            Table.ReplaceValue(tableState,"x", columnName, Replacer.ReplaceText, {columnName})
        )
    in accumulated
```

or:

```
#"Ersatt värde" = 
    let
        columnsToTransform = List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Källa), 2),
        transformations = List.Transform(columnsToTransform, (columnName) => {columnName, each 
         Replacer.ReplaceText(Text.From(_), "x", columnName)}),
        transformed = Table.TransformColumns(Källa, transformations)
    in transformed,
```

Both ways follow a similar approach:

1. Figure out which columns to do replacements in (i.e. all except the first 2 columns)
2. Loop over columns determined in previous step and actually do the replacement.

---

- I've used `Replacer.ReplaceText` since that's what you'd used in your question, but I believe this will replace both partial matches and full matches.
- If you only want full matches to be replaced, I think you can use `Replacer.ReplaceValue` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly! I will think about ReplaceValue next time. For this case there will be nothing other then empty cells or cells containing x.